# group by month and year, including NULL's

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to group all entries by date, and group NULL's into there own group, but I'm not getting the syntax correct.

I have tried

```
db.DateCollection.aggregate({$project:{year:{$ifNull:[$year:"$received-date","NULL"]},month:{$ifNull:[$month:"$received-date","NULL"]}}},{$group:{_id:{year:"$year",month:"$month"},count:{$sum:1}}});
```

This gives 'missing ] after element list' I'm guessing because of the $year within the $IfNull.

also tried

```
db.DateCollection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{$month:"$received-date"},count:{$sum:1}}}]);
```

this gives 'can't convert from BSON type NULL to Date' guessing because it can't convert NULL to a date.

Comment: Are those NULLs actually NULL or are they non-existant fields?

Comment: And by the way.. which version of mongo are you using?

Comment: Some are Null some are non existant, some are blank.